# Show 2 digits and error message when results is negative in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

I need to write a code in R to convert centimeters to the units ***Kens*** and ***Shakus*** knowing:

> 1 ken = 30.1 cm
>
> 1 shaku = 181.1cm

Also:

- Show only the Shaku's result with 2 decimals
- If a non-positive number is entered, the program must give an error message.

I currently have the following code:

```
    convierte <- function(cc) {
                    kens <- (cc/30.30)
                    shakus <- (cc/181.80)
    return(c(kens, shakus))
}
```

Getting this results:

```
convierte(100)
```

[image]

So I need to add some lines of code so that only shakus shows 2 decimals, and that an error message comes out if you enter it **covierte(XXXX)** with a negative number, for example, adding:

```
convierte(-5)
```

Should result as:

```
 Error
```

In addition, I would like the result to show a vector with names Kens and Shakus next to the result.

Any ideas? **Thank you all in advance for participating**

Comment: You can wrap with `round(kens, 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add a stop message at the top along with `round` to 2 decimal points and return a `named` `list` if we are interested in only rounding one of the elements

```
convierte <- function(cc) {
    stopifnot(cc > 0)
                kens <- (cc/30.30)
                shakus <-  round((cc/181.80), 2)
   return(list(kens = kens, shakus = shakus))
   }
```

-testing

```
convierte(-5)
```

> Error in convierte(-5) : cc > 0 is not TRUE

```
convierte(5)
#$kens
#[1] 0.1650165

#$shakus
#[1] 0.03
```

The `list` elements can be extracted either with `$` or `[[` i.e.

```
convierte(5)$kens
convierte(5)[["shakus"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but:

Would there be any way to round only the result of shakus?

Comment: @Adrián In that case you can return a `list` output i.e. `return(list(ken = kens, shakus = shakus))` and before that line, just do the `round` on 'shakus'

Answer (score 2):

Hope this does the job as desired:

```
convierte <- function(cc) {
  # return "Error" for negative numbers
  if(cc < 0){
   "Error"
  }
  # else convert as specified and round to two decimals
  else{
   kens <- (cc/30.30)
   shakus <- (cc/181.80)
   c(kens = round(kens, 2), shakus = round(shakus,2))
  }
}
```

Comment: Curious, when does `return` come in handy? It seems to me it's almost never needed in R unlike say in python.

Comment: Agreed, I guess it is just a code inefficient habbit :)